# Comparing the values of two arrays using recursion?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am trying to check if two arrays have the same length, and the same values in the same exact position.

My current code looks like this:

```
     public class MyArray {
private int size;
private int[] array;
private boolean isSorted; //to check if array is sorted
private static int arrCount; //used to identify which MyArray object

public MyArray(){
    size = 10;
    array = new int[10];
    arrCount+=1;

}
public MyArray(int Size){
    size = Size;
    array = new int[Size];
    arrCount+=1;

}
public MyArray(MyArray arrOther){
    this.size = arrOther.getSize();
    this.array = arrOther.getArray();

    arrCount+=1;
}
public int getSize(){
    return size;
}
public int[] getArray(){
    return array;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other){
    if (other instanceof MyArray){
        MyArray second = (MyArray) other;
        if (second.getSize() == this.getSize())
        return equalsHelper(this.getArray(), second.getArray(), 0, (size-1));
    }
    //else
    return false;
}
private boolean equalsHelper(int[] first, int[] second, int iStart, int iEnd) {
if (iStart == iEnd) {
    return true;
}

if (first[iStart] == second[iStart]) {
    if (equalsHelper(first, second, (iStart + 1), iEnd)) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
}//end class
```

for some reason it always returns true even if the arrays are in different order.

the equals method is called in the main program here:

```
  --main method--
 if (MA2.equals(MA1)) //the arrays are identical here
 {
     System.out.println("The first and second arrays are equal.");
 }
 else {System.out.println("The first and second arrays are NOT equal.");}

 MA2.sort(); //the order of the elements changes
 System.out.println("The second array has been sorted in ascending order.");

  if (MA2.equals(MA1))
 {
     System.out.println("The first and second arrays are equal.");
 }
 else {System.out.println("The first and second arrays are NOT equal.");}
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce "always returns true": See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/XHcxdX). Comparing two arrays of `1, 2, 3` returns true, as expected, and comparing `1, 1, 1` to `1, 2, 3` returns **false**.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling it correctly? I bet your error is up in the caller.

Comment: What was wrong with this answer from yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36120985/3973077

Comment: So apparently to appease @Andreas curiosity of why it always returns true, you should add clarity to your question by showing the 2 arrays you are passing to the method, including how you are calling the method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing an equals method recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120004/implementing-an-equals-method-recursively)

Comment: *"I'm not sure if I'm supposed to call the method with the == operator or .equals()"* You should definitely call with `equals()`. If you "call" with `==`, you're not invoking your code at all, but are simply comparing object identity, and if that is the case, then I win the bet because the error is up in the caller and not with the displayed code.

Comment: Can you show us the equals method that you call this method from?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `size`, `getSize()` and `getArray().length` are all the same number? We really need a complete example, otherwise we're just guessing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes, they are the same number

Comment: @C.Suarez Can you show us the entire class `MyArray`?

Comment: Well it wouldn't fit... I have tons of methods which perform other operations.

Comment: Basically, getSize() just returns the size instance variable.

Comment: @C.Suarez Please read the link I gave you. It gives advice about how to reduce an example down to to the minimum needed to ask a good question. At the moment it's completely impossible to answer this because you're giving us all the wrong information. There is nothing wrong with the `equalsHelper` method at all.

Comment: Okay thanks I include more portions of my code. I excluded some methods which perform other operations (add, search, etc.)

Comment: @C.Suarez That's great. Now can you show us the code that is giving true when it should give false? I'm fairly confident I know what the problem is by the way.

Comment: That's not quite enough. You need to show us both lines containing the `new` keyword. `MA1 = new MyArrayy(..` and `MA2 = new MyArray(...`.

Comment: OMG THANKS! I found out the problem. It was this line of code: public MyArray(MyArray arrOther){
    this.size = arrOther.getSize();
    this.array = arrOther.getArray();

    arrCount+=1;
}

Comment: @C.Suarez No problem. I'm glad I could help. :)

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. It's the same array, so when you sort MA2, MA1 is also sorted. You need to do `this.array = arrOther.getArray().clone();`.

Comment: I replaced that by making a new array and copying the values of the other array into the new array. It turns out that my second array was a pointer to the first array... LOL

Comment: @C.Suarez It's a very, very common mistake. I spotted it as soon as you pasted the `MyArray` class. I just wanted to check that you were actually writing `MA2 = new MyArray(MA1);`.

Comment: @Andreas If you're interested, this one has been solved now.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Thanks for the followup.

Answer (score 0):

First check (preferably) outside of your helper should be to see if both the arrays have equal lengths. Makes no sense to continue otherwise.

`equalsHelper` should return true if end of array is reached.

I see no reason to have 2 separate pointers for index since the arrays are required to be of the same size and the same index is being checked.

Invocation:

```
....
....
if(first.length != second.length)
    return false;
return equalsHelper(first, second, 0);
```

The helper method...

```
private boolean equalsHelper(int[] first, int[] second, int indx) {
    if(indx == first.length)
        return true;
    if(first[indx] != second[indx)
        return false;
    return equalsHelper(first, second, indx+1);
}
```

Comment: Nice optimization, but not an answer, since version in question is working fine.

Comment: @Andreas Code doesn't work for arrays with different lengths while the OP stated `I am trying to check if two arrays have the same length, and the same values in the same exact position`. I was just trying to get him on the right path. If you still think what I wrote was wrong, I'll get rid of the answer. :)

Comment: You are right on that point, but it doesn't answer the question of why OP is always getting `true`, to which there is no real answer, because I got it to return `false`.

Comment: @Andreas Yea yea. I see what you are saying. The premise for primary question itself is wrong, which you have shown. But, the primary question included a part which was left unaccounted for in the code. I thought that required answering.

Comment: @Andreas Anyway, I don't think this is something for me to be nitpicky about

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, iStart and iEnd are redundant. use **.length**

```
String[] array = new String[10];
int size = array.length;
```

If you're trying to compare contents of arrays that may be identical, you need to pass through it manually.

```
    for(int i = 0: (i > first.length || i > second.length; i++){
        if(first[i] != second[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true
```

Your next problem is

```
 if (iStart == iEnd){
            return first[iEnd] == second[iEnd]; //return true or false
```

Your logic here is wrong. You can't directly compare arrays like this. It's comparing the memory address. This will always be false unless you pass through the exact same array when the method is called - which i don't think is what you're trying to do

Array lengths are set manually, so it's a conscious effort to get a difference.

Let me suggest using an **ArrayList** if you're expecting differing lengths. They're also more flexible.

```
ArrayList <Integer> a = new ArrayList <int>();

ArrayList <Integer> b = new ArrayList <int>();
```

Then you'll need to check their lengths. ArrayList uses the .length() method instead of an Array[].length property

```
if(a.length() == b.length()){
```

then if you want to see if each value in each index is identical, you'll need to pass through the array manually as shown above.

Comment: `areArraysIdentical` is not recursive, and that is obviously a requirement. --- `first[iEnd] == second[iEnd]` does *not* compare memory address, it compares two `int` values. --- `ArrayList <int>` is a compile error. You can't use primitives with generics.

Comment: Just have the two arrays as inputi deleted for clarity. <int> yeah solved.